# Using String replace(old, new) where the character just before "old" is not an alphabet

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a small program to replace words that are read from a excel file. The old words and new words are in the same format, something_something or Some_Thing_else. Consider the 2 words below and their replacements:

```
something_else > whatever_else  
thing_else     > foo_bar
```

The issue is that when it comes time to replace the text, String.replace replaces the "thing_else" in something_else so it becomes somefoo_bar. Is there way I can specify that replace(oldString, newString) should only work if the character just before oldString is not [a-zA-Z].

I've tried using either of these regexes and switching to `replaceAll()`. But I realized that it wouldn't work since `replaceAll()` would try to match my string where my string doesn't begin with a alphabet...

```
String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]";
String regex2 = "(?<![a-zA-Z])";
```

Here is the rest of my code:

`oldNames` and `newNames` are `arrayLists` containing the old and new string respectively.

```
Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);

for(int i = 0; i < oldNames.size(); i++) {
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(oldNames.get(i))) {
         if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(newNames.get(i))){

             oldString = oldNames.get(i) + regex2;

             content = content.replaceAll(oldString, newNames.get(i));

             Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to include spaces as an identifier before your string "thing_else" i.e. while you are using regex, then search for " thing_else". notice the space here. and replace it with "foo_bar".

Comment: What should be your output for the input string `something_else_something_thing_else`  according to your question?

Comment: we have to consider all the special characters also. my mistake, space is a special case. it should be for all the special characters.

Comment: The "word boundary" regular expression elements `\b` usually work quite well for this kind of thing.

Comment: @nullpointer something_else should change to whatever_else, thing_else should change to foo_bar. However, the replace() function picks up the "thing_else" in something_else and changes that instead.

Comment: I was more wondering about the output for a single string `something_else_something_thing_else`.

Comment: @nullpointer Apologies, I misread. The output for that is: `somefoo_bar_something_foo_bar`. Also, the word boundary suggested above seems to working perfectly.

Comment: @ArmenHeat well that contradicts to what was mentioned in the question then. `something_else > whatever_else`

Comment: @nullpointer I think what is happening is that, `thing_else > foo_bar` comes in the `oldName`, `newName` lists first and changes the string first. Then when it comes time to replace `something_else`, it doesn't exist in the string anymore.

Comment: nullponter is asking what is the expected result for the input `something_else_something_thing_else`

Comment: Damn, I'm really tired. The **expected** result for that should be whatever I put as. `something_else_something_thing_else > aaa_bbb`. I want the whole old word to be changed to the new word, regardless if _part_ of the old word is the same as another old word..

Answer (score 2):

A word boundary regex is what is working for me. Also, this question is a duplicate, which I didn't find out until I searched for "Word boundary replaceAll()"... oh well.

For anyone looking, the parameter I'm passing to replaceAll() now is:

```
String regex = "\\b" + oldName.get(i) + "\\b";
content = replaceAll(regex, newName);
```